# return form view by ajax Symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony

I want to edit my post without reloading page. I create action, where I send request by ajax to get comment form view, but I get error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Symfony\Component\Form\FormView could not be converted to string
```

How I can get form view by ajax? Thanks!

Comment: Code of controller for "I send request by ajax to get comment form view" might be useful to post here.  By error message it looks like you are adding FormView to response as object, you need to render it first.

Comment: Was about to ask the same but finally answered with the same guess as you did ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your error is quite explicit, I'll assume you are returning your form this way: (if you could have pasted your controller, it would have been nice).

```
function yourFormRenderingAction(...){
   $form = ... //creating your form

    return $form->createView();
}
```

But this won't work since createView returns an object which can be used within a twig template to easily build your view.

You should create a simple twig template which takes `$form` as a parameter:

```
{# form.html.twig #}
{{ form(form) }}
```

Your controller must finally looks like this:

```
function yourFormRenderingAction(...){
   $form = ... //creating your form

    return  $this->render('PATH_TO_TWIG:form.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Of course, you can customize the form rendering etc.

For further details, you can take a look at the [Symfony form documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

Comment: This needs another question and more details about how you are handling your AJAX request. Moreover, some research on AJAX form submission will immediatly lead you to the answer.